# Hide desktop startup screen

Tags: bash, scripts, google-chrome, startup, upstart

I am working on a hardware device running on Ubuntu. One of the most important features is good presentation - in my case not showing the OS startup screen etc. Currently I am using upstart to start the main application. The UI piece gets started through .config/autostart config file. This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
running="stopped"
while test "$running" != "running"; do
running=$(service GBMCP status | grep -oi running)
echo "Current state of MCP is $running" | tee /tmp/startUp.log
sleep 1
done
# To be on a safe side sleep 1 more second
sleep 1
google-chrome --kiosk localhost:8000
```

The problem is that this script doesn't kick in until at least a minute passes, which shows regular Ubuntu desktop with icons etc. Is there a way to avoid showing the regular desktop and show google-chrome instead?

Comment: do you want us that same Ubuntu install for other things also or is only for that project?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you need to do is change/remove the Plymouth splash theme. Plymouth displays the splash image/animation.

You can install a new theme (like `plymouth-theme-spinfinity`, which has no distro-specific logos) and switch to the new theme by running `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`.

If you remove all Plymouth themes, Plymouth is likely to display various debug information instead (stuff like "mounting /dev/sda1" and such). I don't know if that would negatively impact the presentation you want.

You could also try making your own Plymouth theme, using the logo of the place where you plan to put this computer. I found a tutorial for Ubuntu [here](http://www.ubunturoot.com/2010/05/how-to-create-simple-plymouth-theme.html), but I'm not sure if I trust it.

To start Chrome faster, you can try adding it to your Startup Applications. It should start faster than your script, but I don't know if it will start fast enough to keep the desktop from showing. You can also remove other programs from autostart to make Chrome start even faster.

You may want to also configure Lightdm to to skip the login screen, but I think you already handled that.

Since you seem to be making a Chrome-only computer, have you considered ChromiumOS? It seems like a more logical way to do it.